# Replace column values using lambda depending on the condition

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

Using lambda, I would like to replace values of datatable column `item_type` and `item_status` depending on these conditions:

- item_type = "A" then replace with "Apple"
- item_type = "B" replace with "Banana"
- else show original data
- item_status = "A" then replace with "Apple"
- item_status = "B" replace with "Banana"
- else show original data

---

```
command.CommandText = "select [item no], item_type, item_status from dbo.GetItems()";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
da.SelectCommand = command;
da.Fill(dt);

dgItems.DataSource = dt;
```

I want something like this:

```
dgItems.DataSource = dt.Select(...);
```

Comment: what kind of data-source yields `da.Fill`? (is it a typed data-set)? It's much easier for yourself (haveing IntelliSense). And as you wish to mutate the result I would **not** do this using LINQ (this is a antipattern) - use a `foreach` and mutate inside it's body

Comment: Yes. You could either change your `SQL` or use `foreach` loop on DataTable rows once for all scenarios.

Comment: I would say that you are trying to do this totaly in wrong way, such transformation should be in general done on db side as display value in additional column not somewhere in code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll consider your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that doing this in your SQL code to get the desired data in the first place would be the best option if that's possible.

To answer the question as asked though:

```
Array.ForEach(dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray(),
              row =>
              {
                  if (row.Field<string>("item_type") == "A")
                      row.SetField("item_type", "Apple");
                  else if (row.Field<string>("item_type") == "B")
                      row.SetField("item_type", "Banana");

                  if (row.Field<string>("item_status") == "A")
                      row.SetField("item_status", "Apple");
                  else if (row.Field<string>("item_type") == "B")
                      row.SetField("item_status", "Banana");
              });
```

That's going to modify the original `DataTable`.